# Setting a eclipse plug-in to singleton when creating a plug-in project via IPluginContentWizard interface

Tags: eclipse, plugins, wizard, eclipse-pde

I'm developing a wizard that implements the org.eclipse.pde.ui.IPluginContentWizard interface. Thus it gets added as plug-in project template in the end of the plug-in project wizard. All files will be created just fine, but there is one error in the project. The plug-in is not declared to be a singleton which it must be when extending extension points.

How do I do that within the wizard? I figured it needs to be done in performFinish(IProject project, IPluginModelBase model, IProgressMonitor monitor) but neither the project nor the model gives me a possibility to do so.

Edit: For future readers: My mistake was, that I didn't add the extension via the API but rather via generating the plugin.xml "by hand". This caused no mechanism in the background to do their job and thus the singleton directive wasn't set.

Comment: The code that does the singleton seems to be in `org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.bundle.BundlePluginBase`. I don't know how this get called.

Answer (score 0):

This way will be too long, let's use more PDE API:

First, define the template section

```java
import org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.OptionTemplateSection;

public class YourTemplateSection extends OptionTemplateSection {

    //implement abstract methods according your needs

    @Override
    protected void updateModel(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
        IPluginBase plugin = model.getPluginBase();

        //do what is needed

        plugin.add(extension);//here the "singleton" directive will be set

    }
}
```

then use the section with wizard

```java
import org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.ITemplateSection;
import org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates.NewPluginTemplateWizard;

public class YourContentWizard extends NewPluginTemplateWizard {

    @Override
    public ITemplateSection[] createTemplateSections() {
        return new ITemplateSection[] { new YourTemplateSection() };
    }

}
```

Comment: My mistake was that I didn't add the extension via the API. Unfortunately I was not knowledgable enough back then and created the plugin.xml manually, which obviously left out the singleton directive's enabling. Your approach also might be a more fitting one for the task I was assigned with.

Answer (score 0):

In case one does the same rookie mistake then me, I wanted to post my solution I came up after revisiting the project later:

Don't create the plugin.xml manually, use the PDE API of the plugin model to add extensions.

In the `org.eclipse.pde.ui.IPluginContentWizard` implementions's `performFinish(...)` method do this:

```
try {
    IPluginExtension extension = model.getExtensions().getModel().getFactory().createExtension();
    extension.setPoint("org.eclipse.elk.core.layoutProviders");
    IPluginElement provider = model.getPluginFactory().createElement(extension);
    provider.setName("provider");
    provider.setAttribute("class", id + "." + algorithmName + "MetadataProvider");
            extension.add(provider);
    model.getExtensions().add(extension);
} catch (CoreException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```